# javascript regular expression to not match a word

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do I use a javascript regular expression to check a string that does not match certain words?

For example, I want a function that, when passed a string that contains either `abc` or `def`, returns false.

'abcd' -> false

'cdef' -> false

'bcd' -> true

**EDIT**

Preferably, I want a regular expression as simple as something like, [^abc], but it does not deliver the result expected as I need consecutive letters.

eg. I want `myregex`

```
if ( myregex.test('bcd') ) alert('the string does not contain abc or def');
```

The statement `myregex.test('bcd')` is evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
^((?!(abc|def)).)*$
```

The `?!` part is called a [negative lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions). It means "not followed by".

The explanation is here:
[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: This is the answer I expect! Thanks. I need a regular expression rather than a function. My question was edited and answers came up to answer the new version of my question. This is why I used an "EDIT" part to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is there an answer that doesn't match a whole word? Your example "abc", "babc" and "abcd" all fail and where as "xyz" passes. I need "abc" to fail but "abcd" to pass. Removing the `.` and `*` don't seem to work

Comment: @gman : it's unclear whether you want to capture words (like capture 'abcd' but not 'abc') or if like here, you just want to match an entire text not containing 'abc' or 'def'. "Capturing a word" and "capture everything if a word is not there" are two whole different things. However, if you want to go the route of the negative lookahead, here is your regEx : `^((?!((?=\b)abc(?=\b)|(?=\b)def(?=\b))).)*$`. It will capture the whole text (sort of, caution last char) if it doesn't contain any of the words 'abc' or 'def'. So, it will match 'abcd', but not 'abc?' because '?' is not part of the word.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `^((?!(\babc\b|\bdef\b)).)*$`. To capture 'abcd' but discard the whole text if it contains 'abc' or 'def', better check the existence of 'abc' or 'def' first, and if none, proceed on matching words containing 'abc' or 'def'... Buuuuut.. does that have any useful purpose ??

Answer (score 23):

```
if (!s.match(/abc|def/g)) {
    alert("match");
}
else {
    alert("no match");
}
```

Comment: Why are you capturing in your regex?

Comment: Good point! I think I thought if I don't capture it might mean ab(c|d)ef.

Comment: It is maybe better to use `/abc|def/g.test(s)` that return a boolean in this case ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a clean solution:

```
function test(str){
    //Note: should be /(abc)|(def)/i if you want it case insensitive
    var pattern = /(abc)|(def)/;
    return !str.match(pattern);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function test(string) {
    return ! string.match(/abc|def/);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function doesNotContainAbcOrDef(x) {
    return (x.match('abc') || x.match('def')) === null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in 2 ways:

```
if (str.match(/abc|def/)) {
                       ...
                    }


if (/abc|def/.test(str)) {
                        ....
                    }
```