# Javascript Regular Expression excluding a word

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

i am familiar with [javascript regular expression to not match a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449131/javascript-regular-expression-to-not-match-a-word) but it does not help me much. when given a string (with any type of characters), i wish to parse it around two tokens, "//" and "\\". i did the following:

```
var patt = /.*[^"//"]/gm;
patt.exec(str);
```

but it seems to match any occurrences of the characters between the quotes, i.e. "/" and "//". how may i achieve it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Give us an example for `str` and the expected result.

Comment: What exactely do you want? Can you include some **consistent** examples in your question? Such as a couple of Input-output pairs.

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you want to achieve? It's not fully clear what you want to do here (at least to me).

Comment: @RobW i wish to parse a given string between specified tokens, which are "//" and "\\". for instance var str = "hey//you//how\\you\\are//doing";

Comment: @MrIzik: Your question says the closing delimiter is one backslash, your comment says two. Which is it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's `\\ ` and `//`. Click on `edit` question, markdown turned two backslashes in one.

Comment: @RobW: Right, but did the OP do that on purpose...? :-)

Comment: @RobW tried to correct though it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

When you start a character class with `^` (as you have in `[^"//"]`), it means "any character except the ones listed." So `[^"//"]` means "match one of any character except `"` and `/` (it ignores the fact you've listed each of them twice).

If you're trying to match the text between two slashes (`//`) and one backslash (`\`) (as per your question; you later made a comment suggesting it's two backslashes, I address that later), then:

```
var match = str.match(/\/\/(.*?)\\/);    // Match between // and \
```

Note that we have to escape the slashes because the slash is the regular expression delimiter; and we have to escape backslashes because the backslash is the escape character.

The above means "match two slashes followed by zero or more of any character followed by a backslash." The `?` after `*` makes `*` non-greedy (so it will consume as few characters as it can to satisfy the expression). The `()` create a *capture group*, which in the match object will receive the characters that matched in that position.

Example:

```
test("foo");
test("foo //bar");
test("foo //bar\\");
test("foo //bar\\ baz");
test("bar\\ baz");
test("//bar\\ baz");
test("foo //bar\\ baz \\ more \\ more");

function test(str) {
    var m = str.match(/\/\/(.*?)\\/),
        cap = (m && m[1]) || "<em>nothing</em>";
    display("Str: <code>" + str + "</code>: Captured <code>" + cap + "</code>");
}
```

Output:

> Str: `foo`: Captured *`nothing`*
>
> Str: `foo //bar`: Captured *`nothing`*
>
> Str: `foo //bar\`: Captured `bar`
>
> Str: foo `//bar\ baz`: Captured `bar`
>
> Str: `bar\ baz`: Captured *`nothing`*
>
> Str: `//bar\ baz`: Captured `bar`
>
> Str: `foo //bar\ baz \ more \ more`: Captured `bar`

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/eyicih)

Or for two backslashes:

```
var match = str.match(/\/\/(.*?)\\\\/);  // Match between // and \\
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/eyicih/2) (the output is the same, just with two backslashes)

Some reading on JavaScript regular expressions:

- [The spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10) (that's a handy linkable HTML rendering of it; the canonical one is a PDF [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm))
- [Mozilla's excellent `RegExp` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: thank you for your answer though i did not understand how to use it, here is an example of what i am trying to parse -- "hey[[you[[how[[you]]are[[doing"; -- and the delimiters are "[[" and "]]".

Comment: @MrIzik: What do you want to do with that example? Specifically, with the nesting? You may need a greedy capture and a loop rather than the non-greedy version, although those delimiters are unbalanced. Or do you want just to get `["hey", "you", "how", "you", "are", "doing"]` (which would be completely different from the question actually asked).

Answer (score 1):

How about simply

```
var tokens = str.split(/\/\/|\\\\/);
```