# input type number- not able to Remove decimal point

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have this following html code. I donot want the decimal point to be there in this input field.

can someone let me know how to achieve this.

```
 <input type="number" min="0" step="1" ng-pattern="/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/" ng-model="params.data" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript regular expression to not match a word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449131/javascript-regular-expression-to-not-match-a-word)

Comment: What about running a function after focus has been taken away? They enter 093.4 and go to the next input. The function then returns 093

Comment: yea, that would work too. can you please show me a link for that.

Comment: This may be what you're looking for - https://jsfiddle.net/lancelarsen/Tx7Ty/ Just change the "setDecimal" value to "0".

Comment: Or just add to `ngPattern` so the regexp does not include `.`. See the duplicate and replace the `abc|def` with `\.`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek- i got confused there

Comment: `ngPattern` does nothing besides validate the field in a form, it still allows you to type a decimal point even if your regex doesn't match. To achieve what you want you need a `directive | mask | ngKeyPress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, keep in mind that [**`ngPattern`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) is just used to validate the field in a form (`formName.field.$error.pattern`), it still allows you to type a decimal point or whatever even if your regex doesn't match.

You can do it using:

1. [**`ngChange`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) *directive*;
2. [**ngMask**](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask) *module* (Always I need handle inputs with masks I use it).

I made this snippet showing both ways:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular
    .module('app', ['ngMask'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

  function mainCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.params = {};
     $scope.checkNumber = function() {
       if ($scope.params.data) {
         $scope.params.data = $scope.params.data.replace(/\D+/, '');
       }
     }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngMask/3.1.1/ngMask.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="form" novalidate>
    <label for="withoutMask">Input without mask: </label>
     <input type="text" id="withoutMask" ng-model="params.data" ng-change="checkNumber()">
    <hr>
    <label for="mask">Input with mask: </label>
    <input type="text" id="mask" mask="d" repeat="15" restrict="reject" limit="false" ng-model="otherInput">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps!