# Regex filter out IF NOT equal

Tags: regex

I have a object "news" that have the property "url".

I want to use regex to filter out all the objects that have the "url" property ENDING with a specific value, in this case "news.aspx". That is, I want the conditional only to look at the end of that property, and not the whole string. Array operator "endsWidth()" has no IE11 support frankly, and thats why I'm using regex instead.

I'm trying to use Regex to filter out a specific value. Below will not filter out but instead give me all the objects where url ends with "news.aspx"

```
newsArticles.filter(n => /news.aspx$/.test(n.url))
```

I have search and tried to modify it so it instead filter out, like:

```
newsArticles.filter(n => ^(/?!news.aspx$/).test(n.url))
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: `.filter(n => n.url != 'news.aspx')`?

Comment: Some [other suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449131/javascript-regular-expression-to-not-match-a-word).

Comment: I want the conditional to only look at the END of the string, and not the whole string as I wrote. And thats without using the endsWith (no IE11 support), hence regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew .

Comment: Why such a struggle ? Match _all_ lines that don't end in _news.aspx_ : `newsArticles.filter(n => /.+$(?<!news\.aspx)/i)`  https://regex101.com/r/90htnL/1

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-for-string-not-ending-with-given-suffix

Comment: @sln Please re-close since you gave me no chance to change the close reason.

Comment: For the JavaScript challenged it is this  `newsArticles.filter(n => /^(?!.*news\.aspx$).+$/i)`  https://regex101.com/r/R4YSju/1

Comment: Just add a `!`: `newsArticles.filter(n => !/news.aspx$/.test(n.url))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newsArticles.filter(n => !/news\.aspx$/.test(n.url))
```